# Blade - Print variable into variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to print a variable into another variable in a blade template. I have a variable from database that contains "dynamic" data from another variable.

Example:

```
$foo = 'user';
$bar = 'Hello {{$foo}}, how are you?';
```

In blade I am doing this:

```
{!! $bar !!}
```

But the result is:

```
Hello {{$foo}}, how are you?
```

I tried with {{}} but the result is the same.

I can't concatenate both variables. For example:

```
$foo = 'user';
$bar = 'Hello ' . $foo . ', how are you?';
```

It isn't possible because I don't have the control of the variables, they are filled dynamically from database.

Any idea/suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you can't concatenate. That is how everyone else does it.

Comment: I guess  you can concatenate the variable as you are using `{{ $foo }}` then you can use the variable `$foo` and as you said it is dynamic the value can be dynamic no the variable name

Comment: Because I have the content of both variables on database. And both are strings

Comment: echo $bar or double quotes? Shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval` function if the input is not direct from user,and remove `{{...}}` double curly bracket. you can used below code in `.blade.php` file

```
@php
    $foo = 'user';
    $bar = eval('return "Hello $foo, how are you?";');
    echo $bar;
@endphp
```

You will get output as

```
Hello user, how are you?
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some changes to work this our like.

```
$foo = 'user';
$bar = "Hello {$foo}, how are you?";
```

Then in blade you can do this:

```
{!! $bar !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably late, but you can consider sprintf()

```
    $name="Paras";
    $greeting=sprintf("Hello $name",$name);
```