# How to print variable inside variable in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have unusual situation which I have to print dynamic variables inside another variable in blade but not sure if it's possible or how to?

## Example

```
// this returns content of my template which has dynamic data in it
{!! $data['template']->content !!}

// inside that template content I have to get user name like
{{$data['customer']->name}}
```

the problem is printing `customer name`

here is sample result

[image: one]

> **Note:** `$data['customer']` is provided in view page but the problem is how to get it inside my template data.

[image: two]

## Code

My code is basically is just sample code i shared above (it's all happening in blade)

```
{!! $data['template']->content!!}

// inside `content` there is like:

 <h4>{{$data['customer']-&gt;customer_lastname}}</h4>
```

## Question

How can I get `{{$data['customer']}}` printed inside `{!! $data['template']->content!!}`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138850/blade-print-variable-into-variable

Comment: @user3532758 `file_get_contents` probably i don't know how to use your referred link, would you mind share an answer?

Comment: I hoped to give you an idea from that link. I understood from your question that the `$data['customer']` is already stored in the template content string. Laravel will treat it as a string. If you want to print such variables you would need to resolve to using low level functions like `eval`. But if you are open to changing your methods, you could treat the content string before sending to blade; use pattern matching to replace predefined patterns.

Comment: @user3532758 I am open to change my code in anyway that could print the result. that `$data['customer']` should behave as dynamic data which changes based on users.

Comment: Why don't you try my suggestion then. Treating the template content string before sending to blade? If you want I can post an answer to describe my idea.

Comment: @user3532758 that would be the best i've already asked you to publish an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments, you could treat and compile the template string with pre-defined patterns. For example, for customer names you could do this when constructing content text:

```
<h4>:customer_name</h4>
```

And then before sending the data to blade:

```
$templateContent = $data['template']->content;
$templateContent = preg_replace("/:customer_name/i", $data['customer']->name, $templateContent);
return view('yourview', compact('templateContent'));
```

And, in blade:

```
{!! $templateContent !!}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.